# OpenCV building fails due to DirectX

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, mingw, directx

I'm following this [guide](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows) to compile OpenCV for Qt5 under Windows 7.
I'm using:

- CMake 3.14.3
- OpenCV 4.1.0
- Qt 5.12.2

I configured and set the parameters as described. Then started the compilation. It fails with a lot of similar errors:

```
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\directx.cpp:1055:5: error: 'cl_context' was not declared in this scope
     cl_context context = (cl_context)ctx.ptr();
     ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\directx.cpp:1055:5: note: suggested alternative: '_onexit'
     cl_context context = (cl_context)ctx.ptr();
     ^~~~~~~~~~
     _onexit
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\directx.cpp:1057:5: error: 'cl_int' was not declared in this scope
     cl_int status = 0;
     ^~~~~~
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\directx.cpp:1057:5: note: suggested alternative: 'lrint'
     cl_int status = 0;
     ^~~~~~
     lrint
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\directx.cpp:1058:12: error: expected ';' before 'clImage'
     cl_mem clImage = 0;
            ^~~~~~~
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\directx.cpp:1062:5: error: 'clImage' was not declared in this scope
     clImage = clCreateFromD3D11Texture2DNV(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, pD3D11Texture2D, 0, &status);
     ^~~~~~~
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\directx.cpp:1062:5: note: suggested alternative: 'IplImage'
     clImage = clCreateFromD3D11Texture2DNV(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, pD3D11Texture2D, 0, &status);
     ^~~~~~~
     IplImage
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\directx.cpp:1062:44: error: 'context' was not declared in this scope
     clImage = clCreateFromD3D11Texture2DNV(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, pD3D11Texture2D, 0, &status);
                                            ^~~~~~~
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\directx.cpp:1062:44: note: suggested alternative: 'onexit'
     clImage = clCreateFromD3D11Texture2DNV(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, pD3D11Texture2D, 0, &status);
                                            ^~~~~~~
                                            onexit
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\directx.cpp:1062:53: error: 'CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY' was not declared in this scope
     clImage = clCreateFromD3D11Texture2DNV(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, pD3D11Texture2D, 0, &status);
```

I disabled the `WITH_DIRECTX` flag in CMake, then:

1. Configure
2. Generate
3. `mingw32-make clean`
4. `mingw32-make -j 8`

But the errors are still there.
What else I must do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable directx I had to turn off also all the items related to OpenCL:

- OPENCL_FOUND
- OPENCV_DNN_OPENCL
- WITH_OPENCL
- WITH_OPENCLAMDBLAS
- WITH_OPENCLAMDFFT
- WITH OPENCL_D3D11_NV
- WITH_OPENCL_SVM

It was not so straightforward to understand that OpenCL is related to DirectX.